# Remote update/restore of database through SSMS

Tags: sql-server

How can I update or restore a database through SQL Server Management Studio by connecting "remotely" to it?

If I know the "IP address" of machine, what else do I need to do? If a port number is required, how can I find it?

Comment: Probably a better fit for dba.se; also, you may want to start marking some of yoru questions as answered.

Answer (score 1):

If you can connect to the server and you have the rights to do so, you can restore a database. The other thing that you'll need is to be able to get the backup files on to the servers hard drives or a network share that the SQL Server instance has rights to read.

Comment: merdenny, actually the task was/is to connect to the remote machine and take the backup of db. I got only the IP address but the porblem was i did not know on which port the sql server instance is running. So i was not able to establish a remote connection to the database through the sql management studio. That was the main issue and still looking for some help

Comment: If you know the instance name, passing that as part of the server name will get you connected.  If you don't have the instance name, or if dealing with the default instance and you don't have the port number they will need to provide the port number.

Comment: If SQL is running on the default port as a default instance, you shouldn't need anything other than the IP in the Server Name field.  If it's a named instance, you can just append the instance name to the IP with a "\".  If it's running on a non-standard port, you either need the port number (append to the IP using a comma ",")  or the server needs to be running the SQL Browser service so that it's advertising its instances.